# How to DDE a value from SAS to a WORD bookmark that is in a text box?

Tags: ms-word, sas, textbox, dde

I'm trying to get SAS to insert a value in Word (via DDE). Everything works fine **unless** the bookmark is within a text box, then it cannot find the bookmark.

I don't have the option of not using a textbox, I'm populating templates that someone else has created.

```
%macro quick_stats(ins_id);
    ** Open Word;
    options noxsync noxwait xmin;
    filename outdata dde 'winword|system' notab;

    %macro open_word;
        data _null_;
              length fid rc start stop time 8;
              fid=fopen('outdata','s');
              if (fid le 0) then do;
                    rc=system('start winword');
                    start=datetime();
                    stop=start+10;
                    do while (fid le 0);
                      fid=fopen('outdata','s');
                      time=datetime();
                      if (time ge stop) then fid=1;
                      end;
                    end;
              rc=fclose(fid);
        run;
    %mend open_word;
    %open_word;

    **Open document;
    %macro opendoc;
        data _null_;
              cmd='[FileOpen.Name =' || '"' || "&out_directory.\&ins_id..docx" || '"' || ']';
              file outdata;
              put cmd;
        run;
    %mend;
    %opendoc;

    data _null_;
        set temp_sub;
        file outdata;

        put %unquote(%bquote('[EditGoto.Destination = "MyBookmark"]'));
        ** Insert value;
        cmd = '[Insert "' || MyValue || '"]';
        put cmd;

        file outdata;
        put '[FileSave]';
        put '[FileClose]';
        put '[FileExit]';
    run;
%mend quick_stats;
```

Comment: Which version of Word is involved? In older versions textbox content was not "visible". The problem was rectified in more recent versions...

Comment: @CindyMeister I'm using microsoft office 365 proplus (Word v1908, build 11929.20562)